# Formattingthe ietartion of rows to a csv file Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, csv

The code below is meant to iterate `[Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4]` into a csv file. It saves each iteration to the csv code with the `dataframe.to_csv("sales.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)` code. The first row collides with the column names `Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4` and prints the values next to it. I want to print the values beneath the column names like the `Expected Output` is showing. How would i modify the code below so that I could get that result.

```
from numpy import random
import pandas
Values = random.randint(100, size=(100000))
Number_array = random.randint(100, size=(1000))
for n in range(len(Values)):
    val1 = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    val2 = np.sum([Number_array])
    val3 = val1 * val2
    val4 = n * 2
    data =[Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4]
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    dataframe.to_csv("input.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

`input.csv` file:

```
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

Output:

```
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4 49793,48793, -1865417447, 0
82793, 48793, -255248447, 2
```

Expected output

```
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
49793,48793, -1865417447, 0
82793, 48793, -255248447, 2
```

Comment: Why do you want to append  to an existing file, instead of creating a new one? Do you intend to do this repeatedly?

Comment: Anyway, I don't really understand how this is a problem, but: perhaps you can think of something that you could write after the existing contents of the file, in order to make the next thing that you write appear on a new line? How would you do that normally?

Comment: Yea I am trying to do this repeatedly,  so i was wondering if something like this could have been done

Comment: Why not just read the existing data each time, append the appropriate data, and write it out from scratch (allowing pandas to include the header)?